# css dropdown menu is not showing the image at the top level on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have my menu something like [this](http://tinkerbin.com/6HfvGExy).But here I have not used the arrow buttons. In that menu I have used an arrow at the top level. when you will make hover on that menu it is changing the color. but when I am hovering on the sub menus the arrow is not visible at the top level. Here with I am attaching the screen capture of the menu.
Here is the [live demo](http://modulesoft.info/projects/valuepayroll/)

In this image you can see there is the arrow images. These is the normal state of menu.

[image]

This is the hover state of top menu. You can see the top arrow image color has been changed

[image]

This is the hover state of sub menus. Here you can see at the top level there is no arrow at the top menu. I want the hover state arrow image at the top menu here.

[image]

Comment: And what's your HTML? CSS? Do you have [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could see?

Comment: yes the demo is in http://tinkerbin.com/6HfvGExy

Comment: You'll need to supply a full URL for the image file, otherwise it's not going to show at all in the demo. Also, I've not looked closely, but could you make sure that your code (HTML *and* CSS) is reduced to the *absolute minimum* required to reduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the following css-selector `#access #header-right-menu ul li a:hover > span {` to `#access #header-right-menu ul li:hover a > span {`

Comment: thanks that worked but after that I am facing another problem. When you will hover the main menu the dropdown menu also showing the arrow image and also on hover the sub menus the arrow image is still showing. The live demo of the site is http://modulesoft.info/projects/valuepayroll/

Answer (score 0):

The css selector should have been `#access #header-right-menu .menu > .menu-item:hover > a > span`